Proving that $ D' $ always lies on line $EF $ after a $60°$ rotation in an equilateral triangle
Consider an equilateral triangle $ABC$ with points $D$, $E$, and $F$ being the midpoints of sides $AB$, $AC$, and $BC$ respectively. Let $M $ be a point on the line $ BC $. If we rotate the line segment $ MD $ about $M $ by $60°$ clockwise to get $MD' $, how can we prove that $ D' $ always lies on the line $ EF $?
Details and Assumptions:

$ ABC $ is an equilateral triangle.
$ D $, $ E$, and $ F $ are midpoints of sides $AB $, $ AC $, and $BC $, respectively.
$ M $ is a point on the line $ BC $.
Line segment $ MD $ is rotated by $60°$ clockwise about point $ M$ to obtain $MD' $.

Objective:
Prove that point $ D' $ always lies on the line $ EF$.
Attempt at a Solution:

Determine the coordinates of $ D $, $ E $,$ F $, and $ M $ in a coordinate system with origin at $A $ .
Use rotation matrices to find the coordinates of $D' $.
Show that $D'$ satisfies the equation of the line $ EF $.


Any help with the steps to prove this would be appreciated!

Mathjax does not support \( and \) syntax. Use $.

You do not need extra spaces around the dollar signs

Thanks for your advice.@Arturo-Magidin

Method:

Connect $ DF $ and $ D'F $, and prove that $ \triangle DFD' \cong \triangle DBM $.
Since $\triangle DFD' \cong \triangle DBM $, we have $ \angle DFD' = 120^\circ $.
Therefore, $\angle D'FM = \angle DFD' - \angle DFB = 120^\circ - 60^\circ = 60^\circ $.
Since $ \angle BFE = 120^\circ $, $ D' $, $ E $, and $ F $ are collinear.


Is this a serious solution?

Another possible proof: show that the rotation by 60° about $D$ carries line $BF$ to line $FE$. Hence the transformed of $M$ must lie on $FE$.
